# How to get different log level for logfile and console?

Tags: java, log4j2

```xml
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.example" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

This outputs log level debug to both Console and File. I tried reversing the order and, although I think it does something else, adding `additivity="false"` to `Logger`. Both didn't give me the expected result.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does the following documented example help? [How do I send log messages with different levels to different appenders?](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level).

Comment: Man, seriously, it didn't even occur to me to check the FAQ even though the manual section I've been reading is right under it. Thank you, this gave me the expected result. Shame I can't accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the log level with the `AppenderRef` tag.

```xml
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Thanks to andrewjames for pointing to the relevant [FAQ entry](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level).